# Image loading into UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm loading an image into my UIView background as a background color from a file stored in my xcode project. It works fine on the iPhone simulator but when I compile on my iPhone, the image isn't there in the background, which is obviously due to the fact that the image isn't stored as a file on phone. Is there a way to hard code an image so it's transported to different devices, forgoing the need to have an image file present?

Answer (score 2):

When dragging a image(or any other reseources), be sure to check this option: `Copy items into destination group's folder`. In this way, your image will be store in the app bundle, instead to just reference from some path inside your pc.

Here's of this checkbox:
[image]

Comment: Yeah I did that, but it only recognizes the image when I specify the path using NSFileManager. I have the image in the 'Supporting Files' folder as 'wood1.jpg' but to load it as an image in the code I need to use the following code:

    [fm changeCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/blahblahblah..."];
    
    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"wood1.jpg"];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:img];

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why wouldn't use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood1.jpg"];` ?? It will automatically search for the image with the given name inside all images added in our bundle

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried
 adding the image to the bundle in the copy files build phase?

This will put the image into your app so it will always be there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go ahead and try this. What about putting the image in supporting files, like the rest of my images I use in interface builder. Is there a way to specify this as a path without using the unix path?

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me once as well. Remember that if you're using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];`, then with the iOS simulator, you don't need the letters to be in the right case. If your image is named "IMAge.png", then the simulator would find it with the parameter "image.png", but the device wouldn't. So make sure you've got the correct name, the device is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Image load important point:

---

1.Make sure your image below your project document, the true path or relative path.

---

2.Image name differentiate uppercase and lowercase on the iphone but not use the iphone simulator.

---

3.Use Xcode shotcuts 'command+shift+K' to clear your project then run again, judge for if the image cached or not.

---

Run run run!